# three.js - mask transparency with a texture image

Tags: javascript, three.js

I would like to add a mask effect on my scene.
I found this cool jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/4703/

I've been wondering if it's possible to set the white part of that texture transparent so I can have my background object cropped depending on the above plane texture.

I tried to play with the `alphaTest` value but in vain.

Does anyone have any idea on how to reach this result ? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understand your intended result but it should be possible to implement the effect via post processing. In the following live demo, `MaskPass` is used to create a mask where no pixels of the actually beauty pass are rendered. The important code section is:

```js
var clearPass = new ClearPass();

var maskPass = new MaskPass( sceneMask, camera );
maskPass.inverse = true;

var renderPass = new RenderPass( scene, camera );
renderPass.clear = false;

var clearMaskPass = new ClearMaskPass();
var outputPass = new ShaderPass( CopyShader );

var parameters = {
        minFilter: THREE.LinearFilter,
        magFilter: THREE.LinearFilter,
        format: THREE.RGBFormat,
        stencilBuffer: true
    };

var renderTarget = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight, parameters );

composer = new EffectComposer( renderer, renderTarget );
composer.addPass( clearPass );
composer.addPass( maskPass );
composer.addPass( renderPass );
composer.addPass( clearMaskPass );
composer.addPass( outputPass );
```

Notice that the mask object (the plane) is managed in a separate scene.

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/e6p0axb1/5/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was hoping to fin a way of doing it without any post processing method but it works great actually on your jsfiddle, I'm gonna try it

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that the {alpha: true} property of my renderer doesn't work with the composer method : https://jsfiddle.net/x3mkuLh9/ Is there a way to keep transparency on my canvas while using composer ? Thank you

Comment: Yep, the render target has to be in `RGBA` format: https://jsfiddle.net/40gef6sz/